# use dropwizard without web services?

Tags: dropwizard

I'm developing a message-driven module that does not offer any web services (although it might invoke some). The main loop is to listen for incoming messages.
The reason I'm thinking of re-using dropwizard is because, even though I'm not developing any web services, I'd like to reuse the rest of the functionality that comes packaged with dropwizard - database, migrations, configuration,.yml files, jersey client etc. Is that possible (without a hack)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the components that interest you as Maven dependencies. Like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-configuration</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

These individual modules don't depend on dropwizard-core so you won't be pulling in Jetty, etc.